# Plotting fractional powers with maple

Tags: graphing-functions, maple

I am trying to plot the function $(-2(\alpha-1)/\alpha)^{(-2(\alpha+2)/\alpha)}$ in maple,
but I got the following warning

```
plot( (-2*(alpha-1)/alpha)^(-2*(alpha+2)/alpha) ,alpha=5..10);
```

> Warning, unable to evaluate the function to numeric values in the
>   region; complex values were detected.

Actually the function have real values as roots but maple does not plot the values.

How do I plot it?

Answer (score 0):

You claim that the expression has *real values as roots*. However, 
$$
\frac {-2(a-1)}a = \frac{2(1-a)}a < 0
$$
for $a > 1$ and thus especially for $a \in [5,10]$. I am quite unconvinced that your expression is real for all values of $a\in [5,10]$ and a simple check agrees with this suspicion;

```
seq((-2*(a-1)/a)^(-2*(a+2)/a),a = 5..10, 1):
evalf(%,2);
```

> $- 0.21- 0.16\,i,- 0.13- 0.23\,i,- 0.056- 0.24\,i,- 0.24\,i, 0.044-
>  0.24\,i, 0.078- 0.23\,i$

Instead, try the `complexplot` command in the `plots` package, which hints that your expression may be complex for all values of $a\in[5,10]$.

```
plots:-complexplot((-2*(a-1)/a)^(-2*(a+2)/a),a = 5..10);
```

[image: Complexplot of expression]

Comment: But you have forgotten  that the power has two factor. Then  as an axample (-3)^(2x) can be written as  9^x  and we can plot it.

Comment: Maple has a programming problem to give the roots.  (-1)^(1/3) has three roots one of them real and the others complex. Maple thinks the complex roots and does not draw the graph. This is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Therkel response.

If you want to plot only the real part then you can do it like this,

```
restart:with(plots):
plot( Re((-2*(alpha-1)/alpha)^(-2*(alpha+2)/alpha)),alpha=5..50,axes=boxed,color=red);
```

[image]

Comment: Actually Re takes real part only. I want to plot real roots, not real part of complex roots. I think maple has a programming problem for the cases.